# Kubernetes CPU usage

Tags: kubernetes

I am using Rancher. I have deployed a cluster with 1 master & 3 worker nodes.
All Machines are VPSes with 2 vCPU, 8GB RAM and 80GB SSD.

After the cluster was set up, the CPU reserved figure on Rancher dashboard was 15%.  After metrics were enabled, I could see CPU used figures too and now CPU reserved had become 44% and CPU used was 16%. I find those figures too high. Is it normal for Kubernetes a cluster to consume this much CPU by itself?

[image]

[image]

Drilling down into the metrics, if find that the networking solution that Rancher uses - Canal - consumes almost 10% of CPU resources. Is this normal?

[image]
[image]